# Intellij module cannot access resources when included as a dependency in another module

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classpath

I have an Intellij project with two modules.
The first module has MyClass.java that loads some resources in it's constructor using `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/name.jpg");`

The directory structure of the project is

```
myProject
   moduleA
      src
         main
            java (sources)
               mystuffA
                  MyClass.java
                  MyMainA.java
            resources (resources)
               name.jpg
   moduleB
      src
         main
            java (sources)
               mystuffB
                  MyMainB.java
```

Inside MyMainA, I can instantiate a MyClass without issue. When I try to instantiate a new MyClass in MyMainB.java, MyClass gets a null pointer when loading name.jpeg as a resource.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up packaging all of moduleA into a jar file, then referencing that jar file from moduleB. It works, but I don't really like it.

Answer (score 0):

If modules have dependencies between each other (via Maven or IntelliJ IDEA, it doesn’t matter), and folders with resources are marked as resources, then you can access the resource of another module using the following path:

```
"classpath*:name.jpg"
```

If there is a subfolder in the resource folder, it must also be specified before the file.